# iPhone 4S and iPod Models UIView going behind keyboard on text entry

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uikeyboard

I have a UIView with a UITextView and 2 buttons inside of it.  When the user wants to comment on a post, the view moves above the keyboard (this works fine).
[image: Input View]

When the user starts entering text, the UIView and the UITextView will grow accordingly to the content.  This works on every device except iPods and the iPhone 4S.  On those devices the textView and the UIView grow behind the keyboard.  I've tried changing the vertical content compression resistance priority, but to no avail.

**iPhone 4s:**

[image: iPhone 4S]

**iPhone 7:**

[image]

Time for the code:

```
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self updateInputPanel];
}

- (void)updateInputPanel {
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{
      __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
      CGFloat widthText = textInput.frame.size.width, heightText;
      CGSize sizeText = [textInput sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake (widthText, MAXFLOAT)];
      heightText = fmaxf (36.5, sizeText.height);
      heightText = fminf (110.0, heightText);

      CGFloat heightInput = heightText + (51.0 - 36.5);

      CGRect frameViewInput = viewInput.frame;
      frameViewInput.origin.y = heightView - heightInput;
      frameViewInput.size.height = heightInput;
      viewInput.frame = frameViewInput;

      [viewInput layoutIfNeeded];

      CGRect frameTextInput = textInput.frame;
      frameTextInput.size.height = heightText;
      textInput.frame = frameTextInput;

      CGPoint offset = CGPointMake (0, sizeText.height - heightText);
      [textInput setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];

      [strongSelf scrollToBottom:NO];
    });
 }

    - (void)keyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboard = [[info valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[info valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGFloat heightKeyboard = keyboard.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                       self.view.center = CGPointMake (centerView.x, centerView.y - heightKeyboard);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Could it be something with the iOS version and not the device model? Can you give more details on your testing setup (iOS version/device or simulator)